# Bootstrap homepage carousel align vertical center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to make a carousel on my Bootstrap site's homepage. I want it to be at the center of the page (both vertically and horizontally), and responsible, so that it always stay at the center of the page no matter what size of screen my users are using. I can make it horizontally centered but **NOT** vertically. The carousel is the only thing on the homepage besides the full screen background image. Here's the related code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Esther Arts</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- customized CSS -->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font_awesome_4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var images = ['bg1.jpg', 'bg2.jpg', 'bg3.jpg', 'bg4.jpg', 'bg5.jpg', 'bg6.jpg'];
                $('#homepage').css(
                    {'background-image': 'url(img/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'}
                );   
            });
        </script>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body id="homepage">
        <!-- website title, navigation bar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- website title -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.estherarts.com">Esther Arts</a>

                <!-- button group -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Arts</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Google Plus</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Calendar</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Google Plus</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">News</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Google Plus</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Invest</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Google Plus</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="high_container">
            <div class="container" id="carousel_container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="well">
                    <!-- Carousel
                    ================================================== -->
                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb11" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb12" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb13" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb21" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb22" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb23" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb24" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb31" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb32" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb33" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb34" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb14">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></a>
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>
                        </div><!-- End Carousel --> 
                    </div><!-- End Well -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- sticky footer -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="container" align="right">
                <a class="navbar-text">&reg 2014 estherarts.com</a>
                <li class="btn-group dropup pull-right" align="right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Language <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Chinese (Simplified)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Chinese (Traditional)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ukrainian</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter btn-lg pull-right" align="right">
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook btn-lg pull-right" align="right">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS part,

```
.page-header {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.panel-body {
    padding-top: 0;
}

#homepage {
    /* background: url(../img/bg1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; */
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border-style:solid;
}

.high_container {
    position:relative;
}

.container {
    clear:both;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#carousel_container {
    clear:both;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.vertical-center {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;

  text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
  font: 0/0 a;         /* remove the gap between inline(-block) elements */
}

.vertical-center:before {    /* create a full-height inline block pseudo=element */
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
  height: 100%;
}

.vertical-center > .container {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: gold;

  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
                           /* reset the font property */
  font: 16px/1 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact_form {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#myCarousel {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
#myCarousel .thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image:none !important;
}

.carousel-control {
    color:#fff;
    top:40%;
    color:#428BCA;
    bottom:auto;
    padding-top:4px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    text-shadow:none;
    opacity:1;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    color: #d9534f;
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image:none !important;
}

.carousel-control.right {
    left:auto;
    right:-32px;
}

.carousel-control.left {
    right:auto;
    left:-32px;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    bottom:-30px;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    border-radius:0;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#ccc;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background:#3276b1;
    border-color:#3276b1;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAxzQ.jpg
This is the screenshot. The image underneath is a fullscreen background image for my homepage.

When I made a border to see where is **body** element locate, I have this image below, 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mOPL.jpg

I don't understand why **body** element doesn't contain the footer, which is different from the way I defined in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. Hope it will help you. Just set `height`,`margin` and `position` according to your requirement.

```
 container{
  height: 87%;
  margin-top: -10%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the height of div.container is 50% of its parent/top-level div , make its position absolute and set

```
.parent-of-container{
   position:relative;
}

.container{

 position:absolute;
 top:25%;


 ....  
}
```